# How to scrape url's from a website with python beautiful-soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some url's from a particular link, I used beautiful-soup for scraping those links, but I'm not able to scrape those links. Here I'm attaching the code which I have used. Actually, I want to scrape the urls from the class "fxs_aheadline_tiny"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fxstreet.com/news?q=&hPP=17&idx=FxsIndexPro&p=0&dFR%5BTags%5D%5B0%5D=EURUSD'
r1 = requests.get(url)
coverpage = r1.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html.parser')
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('h4', class_='fxs_aheadline_tiny')
print(coverpage_news)
```

Thank you

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: @ Manali Kagathara  I want to scrape the urls of all those headings from the mentioned website, I mean, I want to scrape href (urls )from the class 'fxs_aheadline_tiny'

Comment: when you open the link in the browser and it gives some alert and then it will redirect to page that you want.so, `soup1` will not contain HTML that finds a class with `fxs_aheadline_tiny`

Comment: You probably need to use cookies. You can obtain them from your browser (on my browser I found 18 for this website), I think the cookie relevant for your purposes should be `UserSessionId` that the website sends.

Comment: The webpage is rendered with JavaScript if you in chrome or Firefox, right click on the page select inspect element click network and XHR then reload the page you will see loads of other requests the JavaScript makes. requests does not render JavaScript so you will have to use Selenium or the alternative requests-html https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/ or PyQT or anything else that renders JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I would use Selenium.
Please, try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#open driver
driver= webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.fxstreet.com/news?q=&hPP=17&idx=FxsIndexPro&p=0&dFR%5BTags%5D%5B0%5D=EURUSD')

# Use ChroPath to identify the xpath for the 'page hits'
pagehits=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ais-hits']")

# search for all a tags
links=pagehits.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

# For each link get the href
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

It exactly does what you want: it takes out all urls/links on your search page (that means also the links to the authors pages).

You could even consider automating the browser and moving through the search page results. See for this the Selenium documentation:https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Hope this helps